# How do I stop Android Studio from setting compileSdkVersion to 32 by default on new project creation?

Tags: android-studio

Every time I start a new project, `compileSdk` is set to **32** by default, in **build.gradle (:app)**. When I try to build that new project, IDE shows an error telling me that there are libraries I use that require `compileSdk` to be **33** or higher. That, unfortunately, means that I have to manually set `compileSdk` to **33** every time I start a new project or module.

I was advised that I delete the latest SDK. Well, then I did try deleting Android SDK **33**, but it took no effect. Then I tried deleting Android SDK **32**, too, which only took effect in that when I created a new project, a window appeared, in which Android Studio started downloading all of the Android SDK **32** back.

An other approach that I've found is downgrading libraries that I use.

These are default dependencies that appear in my **build.gradle (:app)** file every time I create a new project:

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

When I downgrade `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`'s version from `1.6.1` to `1.5.1`, everything works fine, the project gets built successfully. But the problem is that I have to manually edit my **build.gradle** file every time I create a new project or module, and it's super inconvenient. Is there any way to change this behaviour?

So I guess there is something in my system that forces a new project to have `compileSdk` set to **32** and `androidx.appcompat.appcompat`'s version set to **1.6.1**, by default. What is it and how do I manage it? Please help me out because I've tried many things. Maybe it has to do with the version of Android Studio? My version is `Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1`.

Comment: Android Studio templates are .jar files actually. I don't think you can "change" existing ones, but you can certainly copy one and make your own. [Here is a 2023 'blog post'](https://www.sasikanth.dev/creating-project-templates-in-android-studio/) of someone who explains the process in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade the Android Studio
`Android Studio Dolphin | 2021.3.1 Patch 1` to
`Android Studio Electric Eel | 2022.1.1`